# draw() function of Processing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, processing, draw

Is possible to translate in Javascript the auto-recall function draw() in Processing? How to simulate that behavior in JS?

Comment: `function draw() { /* drawing stuff */; setTimeout(draw, 1000 / fps); }`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way Javascript on its own but if you download jQuery (https://jquery.com/) you are able to do something that works very similarly to the draw function in processing.

By using a piece of code similar to this you should be able to get a pretty good result:

```
setInterval(function() { 
  draw();
}, 1); //So it waits one millisecond untill calling the draw function 

function draw() {
  //Your code goes in here
}
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Oops, just realized this post is 3 and half years old!